# What's the correct punctuation when using an interjection?

Tags: выражения, пунктуация

I want to use "так" dismissively as an interjection in a sentence like:

> Главное — собраться, а остальное, так, найдется.

Would an ellipsis (rather than a comma) better convey the dismissive nature of the interjection?

Answer (score 3):

Your version is correct but used nearly exclusively in speech. And because 'так' is so rarely used for that situation, you'll need to supplement it with intonation. I suggest you use a similar expression: 'и так', which is only used in this context and doesn't need punctuation. Your sentence becomes:

> Главное — собраться, а остальное **и так** найдется.

The dismissive nuance is elevated by showing that you don't mind **how** something will be done. So you can use one of the following expressions instead of 'и так':

> Главное — собраться, а остальное **всё равно** (anyhow) найдется.

> Главное — собраться, а остальное **как-нибудь** (somehow) найдется.

Also, 'и так сойдёт' ('it looks similar to the target result') is a [well](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=%D0%B8+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82+meme&oq=%D0%B8+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82+meme)-[known](https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82) meme from one old cartoon about a boy who didn't concern himself with quality:

[image: Meme - Boy in sailor outfit, looking at a dilapidated boat "Да тааак сойдёт!"]

Answer (score 3):

In your sentence, "так" is a particle, not an interjection. So there shouldn't be a comma before it.

See [some examples](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E0&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=2&lex2=%22%EE%F1%F2%E0%EB%FC%ED%EE%E5%22&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%22%F2%E0%EA%22&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=) from the Russian National Corpus:

> Человек живет один и умирает в одиночку, а все остальное так, кружева нашей жизни…
>
> В каждом человеке есть одно какое-нибудь качество, самое существенное для него, а остальное ― так, добавочное.
>
> Это основная кривая года, а все остальное так, вокруг нее канитель.